# how to check value entered in input field is already available or not in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I would like to know in the below example how can i check whether entered value in input field is already available or not.

I have an input field, on key press i want  to check the input field value with the values from names array and display error message down if value is already present in names array and also disable the button. If value entered is not present in the names array i dont want to display error message and enable the Add button. Here is the plunkr - https://plnkr.co/edit/rz0tjxhEajz7848Ws3ig?p=preview

html -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body ng-app="test" ng-controller="testController">
   Name: <input type="text"/>
   <button on-keypress="submit()">Add</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

script -

```
var testController = angular.module('test', []);

testController.controller('testController', ['$scope', function($scope) {


  $scope.names = ["name1","name2","name3"];

  angular.forEach($scope.names, function(x) {

    console.log(x);
  });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looping through the array each time , use ng-change and check for duplicate using `array.prototype.includes()`.

[**Updated Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/UK91Sh1aS2PYT7RT8KUX?p=preview)

**Html**:

```
  <body ng-app="test"  ng-controller="testController">
    Name: <input type="text" ng-change="checkName()" ng-model="name"/>
   <button ng-keypress="submit()">Add</button>
   <p ng-show="showError">Name already exists</p>
  </body>
```

**Controller**:

```
$scope.names = ["name1","name2","name3"];
$scope.showError = false;

$scope.checkName = function (){
   if($scope.names.includes($scope.name)){
     $scope.showError = true;
   } else {
     $scope.showError = false;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body ng-app="test" ng-controller="testController">
   Name: <input type="text" id="getValue"/>
   <button on-keypress="submit()">Add</button>
  </body>
```

Added id above to retrieve value from text field

```
$scope.names = ["name1","name2","name3"];

  for (i = 0; i < $scope.names.length; i++) {
    if (document.getElementById('getValue').value === $scope.names[i]) {
         alert('something'); 
         return;
    };
  };
```

Then ran a function to check for names in array and if there alert and stop function.

To hide add class to `<button on-keypress="submit()" class="random">Add</button>` and call from controller `$('.random').hide();`, note it's JQuery being used here.